# How to remove loop paused and resumed DecorView at Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio

After installation from android studio and after any start of software Ive get this kind of error:

```
2021-12-03 10:59:14.606 25952-26054/com.superx V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 6
2021-12-03 10:59:14.609 25952-26054/com.superx V/FA: Activity paused, time: 3980975
2021-12-03 10:59:14.661 25952-26054/com.superx V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 3981031
2021-12-03 10:59:14.664 25952-25952/com.superx V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity:
```

It loopig and looping and looping: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a1zemxgs4o1mnuf/error%20loop.java?dl=0

And this error is loop all of the time without stop

I open software on android: https://youtu.be/gRW4o64VX0E
I click edittext and it is not activating,
I push the buttons and they are not activating.

It looks like some process working.

Temperature of my android phone is higher than normal. It is hot. I think this is loopong problem.

This is source of main activity: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7b43m83358ezpeg/mainactivity.java?dl=0

Im not clear understand. I havent similiar loops with pause and resume. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is. When I start mainactivity I check permissions. I check some perssions and I get loop at OnActivityResult with permission REQUEST_NSTALL_PACKAGES. I removed this permission and an error is removed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).